# in magento I can't delete cookies

Tags: php, cookies, magento-1.4

I am running PHP Magento 1.4.1.1 and I am storing a cookie with user preferences.

I use this to store the cookie.

```
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('lunch', 'user likes tuna fish', (60*60*24));
```

Now this works fine to save the cookie... but if I try and update the or delete the cookie I don't see any change.

I try and set the cookie with new data like so:

```
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('lunch', 'user likes hamburgers', (60*60*24));
```

and usually a second cookie is created with the exact same name, domain and path.

Also if I try to delete instead of change I use this:

```
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->delete('lunch');
```

with no changes to the cookie.

I have also used delete like this:

```
Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->delete('lunch', '/', 'www.domain.com');
Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->delete('lunch', '/', '.domain.com');
Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->delete('lunch', '/', 'domain.com');
```

With no luck either.

Any ideas?

FYI... I am outside of root folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, on this one I ended up solving myself... but was causing the problem.  The variable I was passing while using set was not set itself... send NULL or FALSE.  apparently Magento won't set a cookie if this is FALSE or NULL

So again solution was Make sure value is set.

```
Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('lunch', $SET_VALUE_HERE, (60*60*24));
```

Also I seemed to have more luck using set with a zero at the end to kill the cookie.

```
Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('lunch', $SET_VALUE_HERE, 0 );
```